# Setting up Eclipse for Java

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-2018-12

I am setting up eclipse 2018-12 for java for the first time and I need to import some preferences, which I have downloaded as an epf file. The directions I am following say to go to the menu item file, and to then click import and to then to a bunch of things. However, there appears to be no menu in my window, even though there is a tool bar. How do I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using a Mac. The menu is at the top of the screen (like it always is on Macs) rather than being part of the window.

Comment: Thanks! Im used to windows so I always forget that.